# How to show that the sequence $u_{n+2}= { (2u_{n+1}+ u_{n})\over 3}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $0<u_1<u_2$  and $ u_{n+2}= { (2u_{n+1}+ u_{n})\over 3}$ for $n$ greater than or equal to $1$, show that $u_n$ converges to $(u_1+3u_2)\over4$.

So my attempt was to show that it is a monotone sequence with a bound and then the sequence converges by monotone convergence
theorem.
So I did $u_{n+3} -u_{n+2}$=$(u_{n+1}-u_n)\over 9$.

Now I don't know whether $u_{n+1}$ is greater than $u_n$ or not so I tried to prove that by induction. Base case is given. Assume $u_{n+1}> u_n$

Consider $u_{n+2}={2u_{n+1}+u_n\over 3}<{ 3u_{n+1}\over 3}=u_{n+1}$. So the sequence is decreasing?
Which contradicts the base case. I don't understand whether the sequence is decreasing or increasing? Also how do I find its bound?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $0<u_1<u_2 $, and $u_{n+2}=(2u_{n+1}+u_n)/3$ for $n\geq 1$?

Comment: Yes. It must be a typo. Corrected it.

Comment: I assume that your sequence is in the real numbers. Maybe showing that it is Cauchy first helps you to show the existence of the limit. Afterward, maybe the triangle inequality helps...

Comment: Thanks. I am yet to learn about Cauchy sequences though.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558471/showing-that-this-particular-sequence-is-cauchy-using-the-definition?noredirect=1
this might help.

Answer (score 2):

To show convergence, yes, one way is to use monotone convergence. However $(u_n)$ is not itself monotone. Instead, by induction you can show that
$$  u_{2n-1}<u_{2n+1}<\frac{u_1+3u_2}{4} <u_{2n+2}<u_{2n} $$
for all $n\geq 1$ (drawing the points on a line might help seeing what's going on). Then the subsequence $(u_{2n-1})$ is monotone increasing and bounded above, so converges. Similarly $(u_{2n})$ is decreasing and bounded below so converges as well. That the limits along both these subsequences are the desired $(u_1+3u_2)/4$ follows from $$ u_{2n}-u_{2n-1} = \frac{u_{2}-u_{1}}{9^{n-1}} .$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I am yet to learn about subsequences so is there a way to do it without subsequences. And if given sequence is not monotone then is it oscillating? If it is, then why does it converge? Thanks again!!

Comment: Yes, the sequence oscillates about the limit, each term getting closer to give convergence. Maybe a simpler way to do this is to show by induction that $|u_n-(u_1+3u_2)/4| = \frac{1}{3}|u_{n-1}-(u_1+3u_2)/4| $.

Comment: Thanks again. I will try that. And why does it converge? Shouldn't it just not be convergent nor divergent?

Comment: At that point it comes down to the *definition* of a sequence $(u_n)$ converging to a point $x$. Which is: for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that for $n>N$, $|u_n-x|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?I'm sorry , this might be a dumb thing to ask but I still don't get why is it converging when it is oscillating?

Comment: @it's oscillating for sure, but in every iteration it is approaching a number(coming closer and closer to a number from both sides)